# How to import a local SQL database back-up file to an Azure SQL server database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, ssms, azure-sql-server

I have a project that is running on a local SQLExpress server. I have exported my database to a ***.bacpac*** file.

I am trying to restore that DB to an Azure SQL server. So what I am trying to do is to create a DB on Azure using this back-up file.

How can I do that?

Comment: There's already a microsoft guide for this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-import  If you have trouble you can ask your Azure account manager also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported it through SSMS by connecting to my Azure SQL server and doing import data-tier application

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to migrate a database to Azure SQL Database is using [Data Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-migrateonpremsql?view=sql-server-ver15) (DMA). This tool performs an assessment first to verify the database does not use incompatible statements with Azure SQL Database, and it also migrate the schema and/or the data, as you wish. Download it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595).